# How to scrape a website using powershell and then trimming the output to a single date

Tags: powershell, scrape

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I can't seem to find my first iteration of this question. 
I am trying to scrape a website to produce the date of an updated app. My code produces two dates, so I'd like to know how to trim that down to one string, which in this case should be October 31, 2018. I know how to manipulate it after that for my use but am stuck in how to trim the output.

```
$months = "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airwatch.androidagent&hl=en_US"

$data = ($response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('span') | Where {$_.className -eq 'htlgb'} ).innerText

$data | Select-String -Pattern $months
```

Answer (score 1):

i remember posting to that question ... and i can't find it either. [*frown*]

for your current question, just take the 1st item in the resulting array. like this ...

```
@($data | Select-String -Pattern $months)[0]
```

that will get the 1st if there is more than one ... and the only item if there is only one.

Comment: Or pipe to `| Select -First 1`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - i suspect - but have never tested it - the use of a pipeline, the `Get-`-less `Select`, and `Select-Object` all add a slight delay to the entire thing. [*grin*]

Comment: You are already using a pipeline, what do you think `$data | Select-String -Pattern $months` is? If you want speed just run `@($response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('span')).Where({$_.className -eq 'htlgb' -and $_.innertext -match ($months -join '|')})[0].innerText` at line 3. If that does't work update your PowerShell.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - your example added a 2nd pipeline jump. each takes a SMALL extra step. plus, `Select-Object` takes more time than an array index call. ///// my comment about `get-less select was really off the wall, tho. [*blush*] sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you guys, all of those are good ideas and will help me accomplish what I need to do, you guys rock.